# Pass data on dismiss to view controller outside of navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I have two view controllers, one of which is within a navigation controller. When a button is pressed in controller A, controller B is presented through the navigation controller and is displayed modally. Is it possible for me to pass data from controller B back to controller A when the dismiss function is called on B?

Comment: Modal segue should be pointing from A to the navigation controller reading your description

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegation pattern or callbacks to do this

Comment: I've tried both of those, but that would require me to present view controller B, not the navigation controller. Presenting B instead of the navigation controller doesn't work because I need to be able to present and dismiss the whole view controller, not just B.

Comment: In that case the easiest way is to use  an `unwind segue`

Comment: And you still can use the delegation, for example in A:          `if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
            let b = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? BViewController{
                b.delegate = self
        }`. And calling delegate method with data before dismissing B

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards and navigating using segues, then an unwind segue will do this for you. Here is a simple tutorial that should help:

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/

This stack overflow answer has much more detailed and valuable information on this topic

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass through NSNotificationCentre .

First you need to add Notification Observer and its selector  in ViewControllerA as below :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) name:@"notificationName"
                                               object:nil];

-(void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
  NSLog (@"%@",userInfo);
}
```

Now in ViewController B you need to post notification as below :

```
 NSDictionary* userInfo = your data ;
 NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```